# VHDL synthesis tool won't infer FSM

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

I'm trying to create a FSM in VHDL. However, the synthesis tool that I'm using (Vivado) won't infer it, and instead it thinks I've created a lot of registers and mux.

The goal of the hardware I'm designing is to implement a locker onto a FPGA. I've changed a lot of things in order not to create any latch, so if you see something wrong please tell me. Also, I'm Spanish so some names are in Spanish; if you don't understand something please tell me. I don't know if you need something else like the synthesis report. (Please don't tell me to create just one process, I have to design it using one sequential and one combinational process).

Here's the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity cerrojo is
    port ( boton : in std_logic;
           rst : in std_logic;
           clk : in std_logic;
           clave : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
           leds : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
           intentos: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));
end cerrojo;

architecture archCerrojo of cerrojo is

signal intentos_binario : unsigned(3 downto 0);
signal sin_rebote : std_logic;
signal guardado : unsigned(7 downto 0);
type estado is(inicial, tres, dos, uno, final);
signal estado_actual, estado_siguiente : estado;

    component  conv_7seg is
     port (x       : in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
           display : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0));
    end component conv_7seg;

    component debouncer is
     port (
        rst             : in  std_logic;
        clk             : in  std_logic;
        x               : in  std_logic;
        xdeb            : out std_logic;
        xdebfallingedge : out std_logic;
        xdebrisingedge  : out std_logic);
    end component debouncer;

begin

sieteSeg : conv_7seg
port map ( x => std_logic_vector(intentos_binario(3 downto 0)),
           display => intentos);

rebotes : debouncer
port map (rst => rst, clk => clk, x => boton, xdeb => sin_rebote);

p_reg : process(clk, rst)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        guardado <= "00000000";
        estado_actual <= inicial;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) and estado_actual = inicial then
        guardado <= unsigned(clave);
        estado_actual <= estado_siguiente;
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        guardado <= guardado;
        estado_actual <= estado_siguiente;
    end if;
end process p_reg;

p_comb : process(estado_actual, sin_rebote, clave, guardado)
begin
    case estado_actual is
        when inicial =>
            intentos_binario <= "1000";
            leds <= "1111111111111111";
            --guardado <= unsigned(clave);
            if (sin_rebote = '1') then                
                estado_siguiente <= tres;
            else             
                estado_siguiente <= inicial;
            end if;                
        when tres =>
            intentos_binario <= "0011";
            leds <= "0000000000000000";
           -- guardado <= guardado;
            if (sin_rebote = '1' and  guardado = unsigned(clave)) then
                estado_siguiente <= inicial;
            elsif (sin_rebote = '1' and guardado /= unsigned(clave)) then
                estado_siguiente <= dos;
            else
                estado_siguiente <= tres;
            end if;
        when dos =>
            intentos_binario <= "0010";
            leds <= "0000000000000000";
            --guardado <= guardado;
            if (sin_rebote = '1' and guardado = unsigned(clave)) then
                estado_siguiente <= inicial;
            elsif (sin_rebote = '1' and guardado /= unsigned(clave)) then                
                estado_siguiente <= uno;
            else
                estado_siguiente <= dos;
            end if; 
         when uno =>
            intentos_binario <= "0001";
            leds <= "0000000000000000";
            --guardado <= guardado;
            if (sin_rebote = '1' and guardado = unsigned(clave)) then
                estado_siguiente <= inicial;
            elsif (sin_rebote = '1' and guardado /= unsigned(clave)) then
                estado_siguiente <= final;
            else
                estado_siguiente <= uno;
            end if;
         when final =>
            intentos_binario <= "0000";
            leds <= "0000000000000000";
            --guardado <= guardado;
            estado_siguiente <= final;
      end case;
end process p_comb;
end architecture archCerrojo;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There aren't any errors or warnings, and I think I can't provide a minimal reproducible example because I think that all the lines of code are necessary to know how to resolve this problem. However, if you don't think so, please give me more detailed instructions so I can understand what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: a FSM doesn't need to be recognized as such by the synthesis tool to be one. It just makes it easier for it to transform it, e.g. convert to one hot encoding.

Comment: You have not yet provided a specific problem. [Vivado User Guide Synthesis](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_4/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) (here P. 134) "An FSM consists of the following: A state register, A next state function, An outputs function".  You have all three. What's at risk is only control over your preferred encoding method for `estado`. The process with the state register may not be recognized. Try [evaluating the clock only once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UmsC.jpg). It's a recognized form. State machines are comprised of registers and muxes.

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution, evaluating the clock only once.